# Find out why internet connection is slow (Cisco 2600)

Tags: cisco, internet

I have a cisco 2600 connecting us to the internet.

a ping to www.google.com is 1500 ms: very high.

If I do a tracert I get very fast on the "outside" and then every hop takes 1000 ms or more.
I've phoned the adsl company but they say that their tests were perfect and the problems are on my cisco 2600.
I have no experience of cisco...
Any hints about commands I could try to understand if the hardware's ko or I have to keep on calling my provider?

I update the question with the latest data I get:

`#sh int s0/0`

`Serial0/0 is up, line protocol is up`

`Hardware is PowerQUICC Serial`

`MTU 1500 bytes, BW 1544 Kbit, DLY 20000 usec,`

`reliability 255/255, txload 27/255, rxload 9/255`

`Encapsulation FRAME-RELAY IETF, loopback not set`

`Keepalive set (10 sec)`

`LMI enq sent  1183342, LMI stat recvd 1183344, LMI upd recvd 0, DTE LMI up`

`LMI enq recvd 0, LMI stat sent  0, LMI upd sent  0`

`LMI DLCI 1023  LMI type is CISCO  frame relay DTE`

`Broadcast queue 0/64, broadcasts sent/dropped 0/0, interface broadcasts 0`

`Last input 00:00:00, output 00:00:00, output hang never`

`Last clearing of "show interface" counters 19w3d`

`Input queue: 0/75/11309/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 1587`

`Queueing strategy: fifo`

`Output queue: 0/40 (size/max)`

`5 minute input rate 57000 bits/sec, 54 packets/sec`

`5 minute output rate 167000 bits/sec, 59 packets/sec`

`461062254 packets input, 2656249300 bytes, 44 no buffer`

`Received 0 broadcasts, 0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles`

`106 input errors, 32 CRC, 44 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored, 30 abort`

`475466652 packets output, 2402577905 bytes, 0 underruns`

`0 output errors, 0 collisions, 7 interface resets`

`0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out`

`24 carrier transitions`

`DCD=up  DSR=up  DTR=up  RTS=up  CTS=up`

The MTU suggestion in actual answers was not resolving my issues

Comment: What do you mean "I get very fast on the "outside""?

Comment: I mean as soon as I get out of my lan (start from my pc then --> firewall then ---> cisco 2600 then ---> outside) and get on the internet

The tracert shows a huge delay as soon as I leave my lan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please show us a traceroute to, for example, www.google.com ? If you get +1000ms just after your Cisco 2600, it probably means that someone on your LAN is consuming all the ADSL bandwidth.

Comment: 1 passage to my firewall 1ms
2 passage to my cisco 2600 2ms
3 passage to outher ips 1000 ms 
4 passage to outer ips 1200 ms 

And so on...

Comment: Ok, so you have your answer : someone on your LAN is using all the bandwidth. If your Cisco can handle it, you can try to use netflow to see what kind of traffic is consuming all the BP.

Comment: I don't agree. If that were the case the OP would likely see the same response time between the firewall and the router. In addition, response time doesn't always correlate to utilization. There are many reasons why the response time might be that high, utilization being only one reason.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `show interface` command (at least I hope IIRC on that command) and for any transmit or receive errors from the interface connected to the ASDL modem. For example:

```
Test# show int F0/0
FastEthernet0/0 is up, line protocol is up 
  Hardware is DEC21140, address is ca00.4da5.0000 (bia ca00.4da5.0000)
  Internet address is 192.168.45.1/24
  MTU 1500 bytes, BW 100000 Kbit, DLY 100 usec, 
     reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 1/255
  ...
  5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
     0 packets input, 0 bytes
     Received 0 broadcasts, 0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles
     0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored
     ...
     0 output errors, 0 collisions, 1 interface resets
```

Also try extensive pings form the cisco router to the next hop from the router. The `ping` command will allow you to send larger payloads at a faster rate by using various options.  See if larger total number of pings and a larger payload causes any packet loss. For example:

`Test# ping 192.168.24.1 size 1000 repeat 300`

(Using the `size` argument is also useful for testing for MTU issues that gravyface mentioned)

Comment: When I try to tweak the ping packet size I get no response at all! ping -l 3000 www.google.com results just in request timeout same thing for 1500 size I start getting answers from 1472... Is this helpful?

Answer (score 1):

What's the MTU set to on your Cisco?  I had the same issue with an 1841 that I had swapped in place of an existing SonicWall that immediately degraded the Internet connection.  I was able to resolve it by changing the MTU size on I believe the inside interface as described [here](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk175/tk15/technologies_tech_note09186a0080093bc7.shtml#pppoemtu).

Comment: the MTU set is 1500

Comment: what's the dialer MTU set to?  Try 1492 (`ip mtu 1492`).  On the inside interface, try `ip tcp adjust-mss 1452`.

Comment: I'm trying to find out which correct setting should I use but no luck on their website... Tomorrow I'm calling the support to ask...

Comment: Are you talking about Cisco's Website?  Read that doc I posted in my answer; it explains it all.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm very inaccurate!
I was looking for the correct MTU set for my isp as you suggested :)

Comment: The MTU settings are correct: 1500 on firewall, 1500 on cisco 2600 and 1500 asked by my provider :/

Comment: Your comment above about various size pings makes me think that an MTU of 1472 or so might help your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an ADSL WIC in the Cisco 2600 or is an external modem? If it's external, try connecting it directly to a computer to see if the issue is with the router or ADSL line.

Also, perhaps posting a `show running-config` might help see if there's anything glaringly wrong on the router.

Depending on how your logging is configured, you might find something in `show log` if you're lucky.

Comment: The Cisco 2600 is directly connected to an hardware from my isp, a DCE-3...
It should be a modem but it's using a cable similar to the old printer ones connected to the cisco...
What should I do?